# Update table on a specific date which the user set

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, date

I am using Spring and MySql,

I have an Entity which contains the fields `[ Expiry_Date, Enabled, .. ]`

I want to set the Enabled column on database to false on the `Expiry_date` due.

Note that i need the solution be dynamic because the `Expiry_Date` is set by the user so every record has different `Expiry_Date`.

Is there anyway to do that ?

I tried `TaskScheduler`, but i think it will cause a problem if the server went down, all scheduled tasks will disappear.

Comment: Plese show what you have tried?

Comment: "if the server went down, all scheduled tasks will disappear" - well, you could reschedule those tasks on server startup. Besides that, you could also check the general enabled flag and the expiry date in combination, i.e. the entity is only enabled if both the flag is true and the expiry date isn't reached yet.